# Как записать данные в byteArray из el1

Tags: java, android

```
 EditText el1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        byte[] byteArray =
```

Comment: Чем этот вопрос отличается от [предыдущего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1154374/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-edittext1-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-inputstring-%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-bytearray)?

Comment: byte[] byteArray = el1.getText().toString().getBytes()

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как записать значение из editText1 не в стоку inputString а в массив byteArray](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1154374/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-edittext1-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-inputstring-%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-bytearray)